# Using particles in cocos2d android

Tags: cocos2d-android, ccparticlesystem

I'm working on a game for android using Cocos2D-android and when I'm trying to use the [CCQuadParticleSystem](https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/blob/master/cocos2d-android/src/org/cocos2d/particlesystem/CCQuadParticleSystem.java) class, the CTOR just returns null. I spent hours searching for an example or a tutorial on this and all I found was other people asking about the same exact thing. It just returns null. I have my .plist file in my assets folder - the same file which is working just great with Cocos2D-X and IOS. According to the good people at github.com it should work so I must be doing something wrong but like I said... it just returns null when I call the CTOR with or without casting:

```
CCQuadParticleSystem p1 = (CCQuadParticleSystem) CCQuadParticleSystem.particleWithFile("fire.plist");

CCParticleSystem p2 = CCQuadParticleSystem.particleWithFile("fire.plist");
```

Please, anyone ???

if It's of use, [this](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/396356/fire-plist.html) is the .plist file I'm working with

Comment: Ok, so according to the project's home at: http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/ you should create particle systems outside of CTORs. Well I did and it still doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this example :

[link for plist](https://github.com/wangtz/HeartBreaker)

you'll get the way how to handle plist file .

Comment: I didn't ask about plist files. I asked specifically about CCQuadParticleSystem.